# Form Recognizer- How to Annotating / Creating fields in dynamic subsections documents?

Tags: forms, data-science, extract, azure-form-recognizer

I started analyzing and extracting text from one loan documents,
there is a section "mention previous 2 years' experience". This section will be repeated based on years and business/Employer, let say if a person worked 1 year in one place and other 1 year in another place. two sections will be there in his document with the same title but the content will vary. so I'm creating fields for each field in the section, as in the above example the person has two sections with same name, so I have created fields again for the second section. and trained the model, but what if the testing document has three sections like that person has worked 6 months in one company and 1 year in one location and another six months in another location. It is not able to detect the fields correctly.
what should be done to get the good accuracy irrespective of number of sections?

Do we need to increase/create fields based on documents?

and one more doubt I have, In train documents If we have 5 documents over all, for each document this number of sections are varying, is that fine? or do we need to increase number of documents based on number of sections, like annotating 3/4 documents for each category(only 1 section, 2 repeated sections, 3 repeated sections, etc)?

I tried creating new fields for each type of documents.